# SQL queries with multiple selections

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

```
//Insert a CD supplied by a particular supplier and produced by a particular producer 
Mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO CD WHERE suppliername = "Sony" AND producername = "Gold Records" (CD name, CD type, CD year) 
VALUES ('CDname', 'CDtype', 'CDyear')");

//List producers information who produce CD of a particular artist released in a particular year 
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name from producers WHERE CD artist="Yoko Kano" AND year= "1999");
```

OR Should I include `WHERE artist from song="Yoko Kano" AND year from song= "1999"` ?

Is this the correct syntax? Just want to double check.

Comment: No. This syntax is wrong

Comment: `INSERT INTO <table> WHERE ...` is not correct syntax. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: You need to learn how to use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to properly insert data in your queries. Your short example here is a total mess of wrongly quoted and not even quoted values.

Comment: You also need to check your quotes.  You need to escape the double quotes inside the double quotes (or use single quotes).

Comment: Neither your PHP code nor your SQL code use the correct syntax. But Stack Overflow is not a spell checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a CD, you should be able to use something like:

```
INSERT INTO cd (suppliername, producername, title, type, year) 
VALUES ('Sony', 'Gold Records', 'My CD Title', 'My CD Type', 2008)
```

I'm not going to give you a full answer to your second question since I'm assuming this is homework. I will give you some guidance though.

First, if you want a list of producers, you will need to do

```
SELECT * FROM producer
```

But you don't want every producer, you only want the ones that produced CDs released in 1999. How can you get a list fo those CDs? With another query:

```
SELECT * FROM cd WHERE year = 1999
```

So how do you combine these? With something like:

> SELECT * FROM producer, cd where cd.producername = producer.name and
>   cd.year = 1999

The query that you need is more complex, you need to include the fact that the artist is Yoko Ono but the artist is not in the Cd table, it's in the Song table. That means that you need another join with the Song table. To give you another clue, consider the question, how do I see all Cds released by a particular artist? If you want to see all songs by a particular artist, that's easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Song WHERE artist = 'Yoko Ono'
```

What about the Cds? You could do:

```
SELECT * FROM Cd, Song WHERE Song.CdTitle = Cd.Title
```

Your final query will need to select from all three tables and you'll need all of the constraints to be in place.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any recommendations on where I can read about joining multiple queries? Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome. There's a very good tutorial on SQL here http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/ It covers joining any many other topics.

Comment: Would it be something like this: $sql="SELECT * FROM producer, cd where cd.producername = producer.name and cd.year= year {SELECT artist FROM Song T2 INNER JOIN CD T1 ON T2.CD = T1.CD;}"); 
$data=mysqli_query($sql); 
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
print_r($row); 

}  Out of curiosity?

Comment: Not really, I've updated my response to give you a little more.

Comment: I was looking back on this and I was thinking about something: For the first question, I wrote "$sql="INSERT INTO cd (supplier_name, supplier_address, producer_name, producer_address, cd_title, cd_type, cd_year) 
VALUES ('$_POST[supp_name]', '$_POST[supp_addr]', '$_POST[prod_name]', '$_POST[prod_addr]', '$_POST[cd_title]', '$_POST[cd_year]' , '$_POST[cd_type]')";" for specifics however, I realized when I create the table Cd, the table CD only has 3 attributes and it does not include attributes from supplier or producer. What you have above may not work right?